# O operador & (bitwise and) do Java pode ser usado para interfaces?

Tags: java, operadores, java-8

Trecho de código-fonte da interface [Comparator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Comparator.java#Comparator.comparing%28java.util.function.Function%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29).

Alguém me explica como é tratado esse `Comparator<T> & Serializable`?

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    return (Comparator<T> & Serializable)
        (c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
}
```

Comment: No grepcode tem a opcao de ver o codigo em forma de texto, clica em RAW. Eu ja copiei o método de la q vc tentou trazer pra cá, de qualquer forma.

Comment: @Articuno Valeu! É complicado postar pelo celular heheh

Comment: Esse não é o operador bitwise. É apenas o mesmo glifo. Aí ele está meio que dizendo que o objeto retornado pertence a ambas as interfaces

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Isso daqui é um lambda:

```
(c1, c2) -> keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
```

Isso daqui é um *cast*:

```
(Comparator<T> & Serializable)
```

Esse *cast* faz com que o lambda seja interpretado como sendo do tipo `Comparator<T> & Serializable`.

O tipo `Comparator<T> & Serializable` é um tipo intersecção, que significa `Comparator<T>` e `Serializable` ao mesmo tempo. O uso de tipos intersecção é algo bem raro de se ver em Java, e portanto essa é uma característica da linguagem que você só verá sendo aplicada em código real uma vez ou outra.

No caso, ao usar o *cast* de um lambda para um outro tipo, o inferidor de tipos do compilador vai ser induzido a inferir como tipo do lambda, o tipo apontado no *cast*. Ou seja, a parte do compilador que tenta adivinhar o tipo dos parâmetros e do retorno do lambda vai acabar concluindo que o tipo de retorno é esse tipo intersecção. Uma vez que `Comparator<T>` tem apenas um método abstrato, `Serializable` não tem métodos abstratos e ambos são interfaces, então esse tipo é representável por um lambda.

O compilador verá esse código, como algo mais ou menos equivalente a isso:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
{
    Objects.requireNonNull(keyExtractor);
    class Temp implements Comparator<T>, Serializable {
        @Override
        public int compare(T c1, T c2) {
            return keyExtractor.apply(c1).compareTo(keyExtractor.apply(c2));
        }
    }
    return new Temp();
}
```

A finalidade em fazer-se isso é permitir que um objeto que seja a realização de um lambda seja também serializável, evitando-se que ocorra uma `java.io.NotSerializableException` no caso de ocorrer a tentativa de serialização de algum objeto que tenha em um de seus campos não-`transient`, o objeto retornado pelo método `comparing`.

Comment: A intenção eu havia "pescado" do código, e acho que já vi alguma coisa assim em _generics_, mas não sabia que funcionava em _casts_.